# .htcaccess rewriting condition to IIS webconfig

Tags: php, iis

Right now I am trying to perform a redirect for a RESTful api. I am using PHP on IIS. Right now I am struggling with converting the following to XML in the web config.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z_-]*)$ api.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

would translate to?

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="api_test_redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^api/([a-zA-Z_]*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?name={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Put I am getting a 404 error when I try to access the api.

TL;DR `index.com/api/data` should change to `index.com/api?name=data` but it's not working

EDIT: I have also tried adding it via URL Rewrite but it appears no changes have been made.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to my problem was that I needed to include the entire path, relative to the root directory

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="api_test_redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^path/to/from/root/api/([a-zA-Z_]*)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="path/to/from/root/api.php?name={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```